# Issue with ndk bin in system PATH, when I want to use MinGW

Tags: windows, gcc, configuration, android-ndk, mingw

I install Tegra-Devpack from nvidiia, this pack contains eclipse, android ndk, sdk, and other stuff requried for android native development. This instalation add to my system variable "Path" folder bin from ndk which contains gcc, g++, etc. 
I also install MinGW to use g++, from command line (for example i want to anywhere type g++ main.cpp -o main, and compile), but if I want this, I must add MinGW bin folder to my system "Path" variable which already contain other bin :/ (this from Tegra-Devpack)
Do you know any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android NDK comes with pretty sophisticated build system based on several different gcc toolchains and makefiles. To invoke an appropriate toolchain you have to call

```
ndk-build
```

from the root of your project (where `jni` folder containing Android.mk and Application.mk is located).

NDK's build system does not interfere with MinGW. I.e. you can have Android NDK r8b and Equation GCC 4.8 Experimental coexist friendly in the same environment. This can happen due to every gcc compiler comes from its own binary file (i.e. `D:\ndk\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe`) and is invoked via `ndk-build` script.

So, the solution will be:

1. Add path to `D:\ndk` to your PATH environment variable
2. Don't invoke gcc directly and use `ndk-build` script